# Corosync on EC2 multiple subnets

Tags: amazon-ec2, corosync

I'm working on a HA solution for apache/mysql and i'm going the DRBD with pacemaker and corosync route... I seem to be having an issue with getting my corosync service to see the other server.

I'm using Corosync 1.4 and sense version 1.3 has supported unicast.

Lets call my ec2 servers HA1 and HA2

HA1 - 10.244.19.47
HA2 - 10.196.55.173

-------corosync config-----

```
totem {
version: 2
secauth: off
interface {
    member {
        memberaddr: 10.244.19.47
    }
    member {
        memberaddr: 10.196.55.173
    }
    ringnumber: 0
    bindnetaddr: 10.0.0.0
    mcastport: 5405
    ttl: 1
}
transport: udpu
}
```

---

The issue I think is the bindnetaddr value, i'm not sure what address to enter sense both HA1 and HA2 are on different subnets.

in the log I see this:

```
Aug 31 13:12:57 corosync [TOTEM ] A processor joined or left the membership and a new membership was formed.
Aug 31 13:12:57 corosync [CPG   ] chosen downlist: sender r(0) ip(10.244.19.47) ; members(old:1 left:0)
```

Any ideas what

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can enter the host ip in there. So on one server you'll have:

```
bindnetaddr: 10.244.19.47
```

And on the other:

```
bindnetaddr: 10.196.55.173
```

I had exactly the same setup with my two servers in EC2 and it worked well.

Comment: So you end up with two address for your cluster.How do you manage to connect to one or the other ? Do you use a dns entry with the two address ? Or do you use pacemaker to manage that ?
All the best Vincent