# Add MySQL as a resource to pacemaker

Tags: mysql-replication, failovercluster, mysql-cluster, pacemaker, corosync

I am trying to enable fail over strategy using pacemaker on a mysql Master-Master replication on two virtual machine running openSUSE 12 created by VritualBox.

I managed to complete the mysql dual-master replication, and it seems to work. Server A has `192.168.X.a` as IP while server B's IP is `192.168.X.b`. I followed the instruction [here](http://clusterlabs.org/quickstart-suse.html), so basically my corosync.conf looks like the one presented in the guide, except the **interface** section which is written below:

```
interface {
    ringnumber: 0
    bindnetaddr: 192.168.X.c
    mcastaddr: 226.94.1.1
    mcastport: 5405
    ttl: 1
}
```

***My first question*** is: what exactly is `bindnetaddr:`? Is it the virtual IP of my cluster? If not, should it be the other nodes IP or it own IP? (I mean IP of the server has this config or the other server)

***My second question*** is: what are `mcastaddr` and `mcastport` and what should they be set to?

Then I tried to add MySQL as a resource, so I did as described [here](http://blog.killtheradio.net/technology/more-cluster-fun-mysql-on-pacemaker/). But when I enter `crm configure primitive ip_mysql ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 params ip="192.168.X.c"` I get

```
crm configure primitive ip_my ocf:heartbeat:IPaddr2 params ip='192.168.114.8'
crm_verify[23888]: 2012/12/29_12:25:51 WARN: cluster_option: Using deprecated name
'stonith_enabled' for cluster option 'stonith-enabled'
Warnings found during check: config may not be valid
```

***My third question*** is: when providing the `params ip` to `configure primitive`, should it be the virtual IP? (the one set in the `corosync.conf` file)

***My forth question*** is: should I ignore the warnings?
To be honest I didn't go any further when I faced the warnings, and since I had lots of uncertainties, I thought It's better fisrt to make sure I'm on the right path.

On a different note, I would be more than thankful if anybody could link me to a simple/good tutorial on using Pacemaker/Corosync and mySQL replication NOT DRDB or using XtraDB and ....simple dual-master replication...most of tutorial availabe on web are for DRDB and XtraDB, or other tools. I know the procedure should be the same (adding a resource to pacemaker) but I was not successful on extracting the similarities from those tutorials...

Comment: Nice first post!

Comment: I think `bindnetaddr: 192.168.X.c` should be `bindnetaddr: 192.168.1.0`. It's the network address is it not?

Comment: yes, `bindnetaddr` seems to be the network address to bind to. My IP addresses is `192.168.114.x`, that is why I set it to `bindnetaddr: 192.168.114.c` instead of `bindnetaddr: 192.168.1.0`... am I correct? anyhow, my question would be if this is the virtual IP I have my pacemaker set to.

Comment: OK, you're example didn't show the .114 subnet so that makes more sense. Yeah I would expect that param to be the virutal ip. This SF post might be helpful, http://serverfault.com/questions/418634/secure-iptables-rules-for-corosync

Comment: Also can you compare your setup to this tutorial that shows pacemaker being used to HA apache, http://andriigrytsenko.net/2011/07/pacemaker-and-apache/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer of question one**
`bindnetaddr` is the network address we want pacemaker/corosync(?) to bind to. So if your servers have `A.B.C.x` and `A.B.C.y` as IP address, then in corosync configuration file, you have to assign `bindnetaddr` to `A.B.C.0`.

**Answer of question two**
`mcastaddr` is the IP address to use for multicasting and `mcastport` is the port to use for cluster communication. In order to communicate with each other, all nodes belonging to the same cluster need to use the same `bindnetaddr`, `mcastaddr` and `mcastport`.

**Answer of question three**
`params ip` is the virtual IP. If you have set your `bindnetaddr` to `A.B.C.0` then your virtual IP should be `A.B.C.z`.

**Answer of question four**
Those warnings didn't affect my cluster. SO yes I ignored them.

Beside the links @slm (see resources below) provided in his comments on my question, [this tutorial](http://www.linux-ha.org/wiki/Mysql_%28resource_agent%29) on HeartBeat MySQL resource agent and [this high availability guide](http://doc.opensuse.org/products/draft/SLE-HA/SLE-ha-guide_sd_draft/book.sleha.html) helped me to setup and configure my cluster.

**Resources**

- [Secure IPTables rules for Corosync](https://serverfault.com/questions/418634/secure-iptables-rules-for-corosync)
- [Pacemaker and Apache - Howto Configure Pacemaker Apache fail-over](http://andriigrytsenko.net/2011/07/pacemaker-and-apache/)